# Чи є форма "бабів" (родовий відмінок множини слова "баба") розмовною?

Tags: відмінювання, іменники

Майже винятково зустрічаю форму *"бабів"* тільки у вусному мовленні і переважно в жартівливому контексті, хоча словникові статті наводять дві паралельні нормативні форми *"баб"* і *"бабів"*, так само як і для деяких інших слів. Наприклад, *"легенів"* є абсолютно природньою формою в будь-якому контексті і в цілому навіть уживанішою від *"легень"*.

Чи є ж *баби* із закінченням `-ів` суто розмовним явищем або ж усе таки така форма є допустимою, наприклад, в публіцистиці?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У підручниках [зустрічається](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/imen/f1.htm) наступне:

VI. Особливості форм іменників родового відмінка множини.

4. Нетипові закінчення :

   2. `-ів` мають іменники *тесля* (*тесл**ів***), *сусіда* (*сусід**ів***); *староста* (*старост**ів*** і *старост*), *баба* (*баб**ів*** і *баб*), *губа* (*губ**ів*** і *губ*), *легеня* (*леген**ів*** і *легень*).

Стаття за посиланням містить досить розлогий список нетипових закінчень.

Цю ж інформацію — наскільки я розумію, цілком — запозичено до [відповідної статті](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#I_.D0.B2.D1.96.D0.B4.D0.BC.D1.96.D0.BD.D0.B0) в українській Вікіпедії і до досить поважних підручників, наприклад,
О. Журенко: [**«Українська без помилок. Говоримо і пишемо правильно»**](https://www.bookclub.ua/catalog/e-books/e-books-learning/product.html?id=34895)
— без будь-яких позначок «розмовна форма» тощо.

Тому, напевне, можна вважати таку форму усталеною у сучасній українській мові і, як наслідок, **допустимою** в офіційній мові і публіцистиці. Варто також враховувати, що саме слово *баба* є досить просторічним, але форма множини на `-ів` не додає до нього додаткової «просторікуватості».